# Play to a certain point in a video in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, video, windows-8, mediaelement

I am creating an app for Windows 8 in C# and XAML.  I have included a video in a media element with play and pause button but I want to include another button that, when clicked, makes the video play to a certain point and then pause.  Is this possible?

I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138682/stop-video-at-specific-position-using-windows-media-player-sdk) which is doing the same thing but with the windows media player sdk. I'm not very knowledgable about C# so I'd appreciate any advice.

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
//Play method

if(ispaused == true && isplaying == false)
{
  VideoPlayer.Play();
}

//Pause method

if(ispaused == false && isplaying == true)
{
  VideoPlayer.Pause();
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code about how you are currently handling play and pause button?

Comment: Code added.  I took the simplest approach I could to this. I looked at one of the samples on the MSDN website.

Comment: @MillyMonster - Does this code even start the video?  Why don't you just use the WMP SDK?

Comment: Yes it starts the video when the button is clicked.  I will look into the WMP SDK then. I am confused about how it would work with a media element in an app though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`MediaElement.Markers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.markers.aspx) property and the [`MediaElement.MarkerReached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.markerreached) event like this:

Specify an event handler for the `MarkerReached` event:

```
VideoPlayer.MarkerReached += new TimelineMarkerRoutedEventHandler(VideoPlayer_MarkerReached);
```

Then add a [`TimelineMarker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.timelinemarker.aspx) to your video:

```
VideoPlayer.Markers.Add(new TimelineMarker() {
        Time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
        Type = "ForcePause",
        Text = "Test"} );
```

And finally add code to your event handler:

```
private void VideoPlayer_MarkerReached(object sender, TimelineMarkerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // you can check the type if you want to be safe
    if (e.Marker.Type.Equals("ForcePause"))
    {
        VideoPlayer.Pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  That makes perfect sense. Thanks. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to play a Background Media Player (for e.g., an audio file) which would start from a specific time and would work for a certain duration, then this code snippet could also be useful:

```
    StorageFile mediaFile = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFileAsync(fileName);//the path
    BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetFileSource(mediaFile);
    BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000/*enter the start time here*/);
    BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Play();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000/*for how long you want to play*/));
    BackgroundMediaPlayer.Shutdown();//stops the player
```