# Start and stop video Windows Media Player at specific times

Tags: c#

I am using Windows Media Player object for playing video in my C# winforms project.

```
 VideoPlayer.URL = "C:\test.avi";
```

My test.avi duration is 12 seconds. I would like to play that between 4 and 8 seconds.

I can start video from 4 second as below;

```
VideoPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = 4
```

So how can i stop the video 8th seconds after playing video?

Comment: my guess would be the PositionChanged event - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms909951.aspx (sorry not got visual studio in front of me)

Comment: thank you very much. i tested that event but event triggered just one time at 3 seconds. if event trigger every seconds, i can control stop time.

Comment: Kerberos, I don't know much about the wmp sdk but you could always have a timer with a 4 second interval and use that event to stop

Comment: @Sayse thank you for your suggestion. if i find to use native event of WMP that will be so much better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a timer to do so:

```
private Timer tmrWmpPlayerPosition;
private TimeSpan StopPosition;

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wmpPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = 4;
    StopPosition=TimeSpan.Parse("00:20:20");
    StopWmpPlayerTimer();
    StartWmpPlayerTimer();
}

private void tmrWmpPlayerPosition_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((Convert.ToInt32(StopPosition.TotalSeconds) != Convert.ToInt32(wmpPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition))) return;
    wmpPlayer.Ctlcontrols.pause();
    StopWmpPlayerTimer();
}

private void StartWmpPlayerTimer()
{
    tmrWmpPlayerPosition = new Timer();
    tmrWmpPlayerPosition.Tick += new EventHandler(tmrWmpPlayerPosition_Tick);
    tmrWmpPlayerPosition.Enabled = true;
    tmrWmpPlayerPosition.Interval = 1000;
    tmrWmpPlayerPosition.Start();
}

private void StopWmpPlayerTimer()
{
    if (tmrWmpPlayerPosition != null)
        tmrWmpPlayerPosition.Dispose();
    tmrWmpPlayerPosition = null;
}
```